# Can I test if command prompt support unicode in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, prompt

Is there a simple test (or trick) I can run on Windows command line to know if it supports unicode?

For the context, I'm using Node.js - but I'm pretty confident I could adapt any solutions.

Comment: So you want to check what the current code page and font are set to for the command prompt? `chcp` by itself will return the code page in use. For the current font you'll probably have to check where it's stored in the registry and retrieve the value.

Comment: But how would I found the current font?

Comment: If I find the reg key I'll let you know, although perhaps someone will come up with a better idea for detection.